# Get file extension with bash script

Tags: bash, sh

i' m trying to extract the file extension in bash without using regex.
i' ve tried the following

```
extension = $(echo $1 | cut -f 2 -d '.')
```

extension is the variable 
$1 contains something like: file.txt or file.pdf etc.
this code is outputting:

```
./prova.sh: 3: ./prova.sh: extension: not found
```

Comment: you can't have spaces around the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension=$(echo sample.txt | cut -f 2 -d '.')
echo $extension
```

Above command will give you the output as expected **`txt`**